# Can Apache airflow be used on Windows? What should be done in advance?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, airflow

I know Apache airflow doesn't support Windows. But I know I can also use windows using wsl. The main question is:

1. Can I get selenium crawling or api through Apache airflow without using wsl?
2. If #1 is impossible, is it possible using wsl??
3. If use Apache airflow, what should be preceded?

Comment: You can develop on Airflow in Windows (with breeze) but other than that airflow doesn't work on Windows. Check https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airflow doesn't support Windows (see Github [issue](http://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10388))

You can however, develop on Airflow in Windows using [Breeze](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/BREEZE.rst#docker-in-wsl-2) with docker WSL 2